# My beacon disappears after few seconds on didRangeBeaconsInRegion but i am near to my beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

**Note**:
I checked on multiple device still no improvement and i made my beacon frequency to 2000ms but still facing this problem

I am facing a issue beacon detection is stable for few second but after that it disappears and then it detects the beacon .I am struck on this one suggestion and code sample are appreciated !!

**Code**

```
    this.beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(500);
    beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(500);
    enableBackgroundMode(true);
    beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);
    this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
    this.beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
    this.beaconManager.setDebug(true);
    this.beaconManager.bind(this);




   this.beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            Log.e(TAG, "beacons size=>" + beacons.size());

            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
               //my code 
             }
  }
 });
```

**LogCat:**

```
10-12 12:33:48.381 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:49.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:50.356 12357-12881/com.mypackageName.android D/RangeState: adding id1: 87f8acb5-9ad0-29a7-204c-f080e2b55c0d id2: 10 id3: 1 to existing range for: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangedBeacon@26eeaf3b
10-12 12:33:50.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:51.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:52.381 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:52.391 12357-12880/com.mypackageName.android D/RangeState: adding id1: 87f8acb5-9ad0-29a7-204c-f080e2b55c0d id2: 10 id3: 1 to existing range for: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangedBeacon@26eeaf3b
10-12 12:33:53.381 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:54.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:54.396 12357-12880/com.mypackageName.android D/RangeState: adding id1: 87f8acb5-9ad0-29a7-204c-f080e2b55c0d id2: 10 id3: 1 to existing range for: org.altbeacon.beacon.service.RangedBeacon@26eeaf3b
10-12 12:33:55.381 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:56.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:57.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:58.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:33:59.381 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:34:00.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:34:01.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
10-12 12:34:02.376 12357-12357/com.mypackageName.android D/Callback: attempting callback via global broadcast intent: ComponentInfo{com.mypackageName.android/org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconIntentProcessor}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the lines:

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(500);
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(500);
```

Without these lines (using default settings), the library will scan constantly in the foreground.  With those lines present, it will only scan a half second at a time, making it likely it will miss transmissions by your beacon and lead to dropouts in detections.

Comment: i will try it for foreground.How about background scanning?

Comment: For background scanning, the BackgroundPowerSaver class is recommended.  It will auto switch your app between background and foreground mode.  By default, background scans run for 10 seconds every 5 min (every 15 min on Android 8+), and a low power scan is constantly running on Android 5+ in the background until beacons are first discovered.  This is all default behavior if using BackgroundPowerSaver.

Comment: okay thanks a lot.Love your product and the way you gave support to it :-)